# $_POST[] - to different submit buttons that are not constant

Tags: php, mysql

I got stuck on some tricky situation.
Well, here's the important part of the code:

```
> if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row["name"];
        $votes = $row["votes"];

        echo " name: '" .$name. "' - votes: '" .$votes. "' <input type='submit' name='".$name."' value='".$name."' ><br>";
    }
    if (isset($_POST[''])) {

    } 
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
 }
```

What I'm trying to do is printing the table row's with a submit button  near each row, which works perfectly fine.
Now, I want the submit button to send data for the db once pressed..
The problem is there's more then one button, and each button gets a different name (by the data from the database table) (as shown in the code).
So how exactly do I call each button specifically from the **POST[]**, because as you can see the if statement is out of the while loop. Help please!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try to create a form for each row like this

```
<?
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row["name"];
        $votes = $row["votes"];
        echo '<form method="POST" action="script.php">';
        echo " name: '" .$name. "' - votes: '" .$votes. "' <input type='submit' name='".$name."' value='".$name."' ><br>";
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="submitted_vote" value="'.$row['id'].'" />';
        echo "</form>"

    }
 }
if (isset($_POST['submitted_vote'])) {
    echo 'The submmitted vote is : '.$_POST['submitted_vote'];
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: hey, i didn't get the purpose of the hidden input, how the id will help?

Comment: You can only submit one form, so you can know the selected row with id in hidden field. Or may be i don't understand the question. But you don't need to put condition in your loop

Comment: yeah but according to what you wrote in the if statement, it doesn't even take the button in the POST[].. so it can't even recognize a button pressed

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're using different a different `name` attribute for each submit button.  You want to use the same name for each submit button with a different value, and your form will only submit the value for the clicked button.

For example:

```
<form action="46792098.php" method="post">
<div>
<button type="submit" name="submit_id" value="1">1</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_id" value="2">2</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_id" value="3">3</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_id" value="4">4</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit_id" value="5">5</button>
</div>
</form>
```

If the PHP code is:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

And you click the #5 button, your output would be:

```
array (size=1)
  'submit_id' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Then your logic would just check the `submit_id` form parameter to determine which button was clicked.

Comment: sorry i'm very rusty in the field.. can you relate specifically to my code??.. my final wish is that when I press the button (that printed with each row) it will add +1 to the table column in the db, to the specific row.. thank you !

Comment: You don't need the hidden field if you store that ID on each submit button named `submitted_vote` instead. You wouldn't check `$_POST` right after rendering the HTML. You need to catch the form post after the submit. If you use the same script for both, you'd check for the form submit and handle it, otherwise render the form.